# UILabel not align center on UINavigationBar in iPhone

Tags: iphone, sdk, uilabel, uinavigationbar

I need to align UILabel text center on UINavigationBar. I have implemented all the steps but some how its not center Align. Below is code.

```
   UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
   titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   [titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
   self.titleLabel.text = title;
   self.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
   self.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
   self.titleLabel.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth = NO;
   self.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
   [self.titleLabel sizeToFit];
   float titlePadding = 60.0f;
   self.titleLabel.left = titlePadding;
   self.titleLabel.width = self.width - 2 * titlePadding;
   self.titleLabel.top = ceilf(self.frame.size.height / 2 -      self.titleLabel.frame.size.height / 2);
```

Please help me with this

Comment: Use self.title = @"SOMETEXT"; instead of custom code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This It will help

```
 UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
 label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
 label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
 label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                     // ^-Use UITextAlignmentCenter for older SDKs.
 label.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; // change this color
 self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
 label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"PageThreeTitle", @"");
 [label sizeToFit];
```